# Session diplay page to function and back to display page PHP

Tags: php, ajax, session

I have a problem. My session is already set but I want to create one more session to my edit. I set a session in my edit page and I retrieve it in function but if I goin' back to my edit the variable of my session is already deleted. Any one can help me.

edit page:

```
$plate_no = $_POST["plate_no"];
$_SESSION["plate_no"] = $plate_no;
$plate_no_view = $_SESSION['plate_no'];

        var perfTimes = $(this).serialize();
    $.post("functionedit.php", {result: perfTimes, txt1: mytxt1,  txt2: mytxt2,  txt3: mytxt3 },   function(data) {
           if (data.errors) {
               var alertErrors = "The following errors were found: ";
                $.each(data.errors, function(index, error){
                      alertErrors += "\n" + "\n" + error.message;//Add each error in a new line 

                  });
                alert(alertErrors);} 
            else {
            alert(data.message);
           window.location.href = data.redirect; }
            }, "json");
    });
        });
```

function page:

```
    $mydata = $_POST["result"];
            $inputs = [];
    parse_str($mydata, $inputs);
    extract($inputs);
    $errors = [];
    $_SESSION["plate_no"] == true;

     if(empty($errors)) {
         mysql_query("update cars set horse_power = '$horse_power' , torque = '$torque' , transmission = '$trasmission_char $trasmission_no' , drive_train = '$drive_train' , dimensional = '$length/$width/$height' , seating = '$seating' , car_condition = '$condition' , air_bag='$air_bag' , wheels = '$wheel_front/$wheel_rear'  , suspensions = '$suspensions_front/$suspensions_rear'  ,  brakes='$brake_front/$brake_rear' , eng_type = '$eng_type' , fuel_type = '$fuel_type' , selling_price='$selling_price' where plate_no = '$plate_no'");

   if(isset($_POST["txt1"])){
    for($i=0;$i<=count($_POST["txt1"])-1;$i++){
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO expenses VALUES ('','$plate_no', '". $_POST["txt1"][$i] ."','". $_POST["txt2"][$i] ."',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '". $_POST["txt3"][$i] ."')");
                            }
                        }
       $response = array(
       'message' => 'Successfully Edited',
        'redirect' => "edit.php"

   );

  echo json_encode($response);

        }else {
        $response = array(
            'errors' => $errors
        );

        echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Comment: $_SESSION["plate_no"] == true; shoudl be with one = no?

Answer (score 0):

1)

This isn't going to work as only session variables `$_SESSION[]` are retained between page loads. Also you're not calling `session_start()`

```
 $plate_no = $_POST["plate_no"];
 $_SESSION["plate_no"] = $plate_no;
```

functions page

```
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO expenses VALUES ('','$plate_no', '"
```

2)

You have SQLInjection vulnerabilities

3)

Don't use `mysql*` functions, they're out dated and dangerous, use `mysqli*` or `pdo` instead